# Delphi 7 with..do statement doesen't work with variant variable

Tags: excel, delphi, with-statement

I'm working with Microsoft Excel via Delphi 7. It works fine but while formatting rows and ranges I have to write such long strings.

```
XLApp.Workbooks[1].WorkSheets[NameDoc].Range['A19:L19'].Font.Bold := true;
```

So I want to get rid of hard work and do it via "with..do" statement like this

```
with XLApp.Workbooks[1].WorkSheets[NameDoc] do
begin
  Range['A19:L19'].Font.Bold := true;
end;
```

But at compilation stage I see this error

```
Record, object or class type required
```

on string - "with..do".

I creating Excel object this way

```
XLApp: Variant;
XLApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
```

I consider that with..do statement doesen't works with variant type variable, but I want to know whether I'm right or not? And if I'm right is there any workaround to make it work?

Answer (score 4):

Variant can be anything or nothing at all - compiler doesn't know it and cannot know: it is so called "dynamically typed value". Since it does not know - it does not know if there would be any members (properties, methods) and if there would - what names would they have.

To get the benefits of strong compile-time typing - including using of `with` but not only - you have to use interface variables, those that are provided by TExcelApplication component and underlying unit having those values "statically typerd" - thus providing for Delphi compiler to know value types when compiling, in before running. There are plenty of types like iWorsksheet, iRange and others in that unit.

- [Borland Delphi 7 TExcelApplication.Connect works on office machines but not at client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895286)
- http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=157889
- http://delphikingdom.ru/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=1270

However, since that is about reference-counting and lifetime I'd suggest you go with explicit use of temp variables rather than using with `with` and implicit invisible variables. Since you cannot control their lifespan and their clearance you might hit the wall in some unexpected place later. I did.

```
var tmpR: iRange; // assuming we have statically-typed API
// for example - providing we using ExcelXP or Excel2000 unit

tmpR := XLApp.Workbooks[1].WorkSheets[NameDoc];

tmpR.Range['A19:L19'].Font.Bold := true; // instead of with

with tmpR do // also possible but gives little benefit now
begin        //    when we made a dedicated temp var
  Range['A19:L19'].Font.Bold := true;
end;

tmpR := nil; // crucial unless the most short and simplistic functions
// just release hold on Excel's object - let it manage its memory freely,
// by letting Excel know your program no more uses that object.
```

Also read

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model

Answer (score 3):

> Can `with` be used with a `Variant`?

No.

You can use `with` for types whose members are known at **compile time**. But variants, for which the `.` operator is evaluated at **run time**, do not fall into this category. Hence `with` is not available for variants.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements#With_Statements) says, with my emphasis:

> A with statement is a shorthand for referencing the fields of a record
>   or the fields, properties, and methods of an object. The syntax of a
>   with statement is:
>
> ```
> with obj do statement
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> with obj1, ..., objn do statement
> ```
>
> where obj is an expression yielding a reference to a **record, object
>   instance, class instance, interface or class type (metaclass)
>   instance**, and statement is any simple or structured statement.

Comment: Thanks. I was guessing it but I wanted the proof.

Comment: with all my preference for WITH, knowing how little documented and predictable ARC is in DCC  regarding interfaces, I'd rather avoid using with with loooong multi-dot COM-expressions.